# Why joiner doesn't have not equal to operator in Informatica?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Why doesn't [Informatica](http://www.selectorweb.com/informatica.html)'s joiner transformation support **!=**, **>=**, **<=** operators?

Why should they come up with a concept like **lookup**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joiner transformation is used for vertical consolidation.
e.g

```
order-tbl
order-id, item-id, item-qty

item-tbl
item-id, item-price, item-desc
```

Using a join condition on order-tbl.item-id = item-tbl.item-id you could print a report like this

```
order-id, item-id, item-price, item-desc
```

For vertical consolidation, I can't think of a scenerio needing other conditions like !=, >=, <=.

With lookup transformation, some core ETL tasks are made easy like

1. identifying if the incoming record is a new record (primary key doesn't exist) or an update to the existing record;
2. lookup a value e.g. lookup item-price from item-tbl to calculate order total.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can join heterogeneous  sources with a non-equi join condition using a Lookup Transformation's "Multi Match" feature

You can download sample from following Informatica Marketplace

https://community.informatica.com/solutions/mapping_multi_match_lookup_join

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing how this is an answer to the question.